# Django or python manipulate email addresses and reason about domains

Tags: python, django, email, email-validation

I want to be able to parse email addresses to isolate the domain part, and test if an email address is part of a given domain.

The `email` module doesn't, as far as I can tell, do that. Is there anything worth using to do this other than the usual string handling and regex routines?

**Note:** I know how to deal with python strings. I don't need basic recipes, although awesome recipes are welcome.

The problem here is essentially that email addresses have the format (schematically) `userpart@sub\.domain\.[sld]+\.tld`.

Stripping the part before the @ is easy; the hard part is parsing the domain to work out which parts are subdomains on a larger organisation's domain, rather than generic second-level (or, I guess even higher order) public domains.

Imagine parsing `user@mail.organisation.co.uk` to find that the organisation's domain name is `organisation.co.uk` and so be able to match both `mail.organisation.co.uk` and `finance.organisation.co.uk` as subdomains of `organisation.co.uk`.

There are basically two possible (non-dns-based) approaches: build a finite automaton that knows about all generic slds and their relation to the tld (including popular 'fake' slds like `uk.com`), or try to guess, based on the knowledge that there must be a tld, and assuming that if there are three (or more) elements, the second-level domain is generic if it has fewer than three/four characters. The relative drawbacks of each approach should be obvious.

The alternative is to look through DNS entries to work out what is a registered domain, which has its own drawbacks.

In any case, I would rather piggyback on the work of others.

Comment: Assuming a correctly formated address, I see no reason why basic string handling wouldn't be enough.

Comment: @madjar: See my explanation above.

Comment: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

Comment: @dm03514 If you submit that as an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @dm03514's comment, there is a python library that does exactly this: [tldextract](http://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract):

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> tldextract.extract('foo@bar.baz.org.uk')
ExtractResult(subdomain='bar', domain='baz', tld='org.uk')
```

Answer (score 0):

With this simple script, we replace `@` with `@.` so that our domain is terminated and the `endswith` won't match a domain ending with the same text.

```
def address_in_domain(address, domain):
    return address.replace('@', '@.').endswith('.' + domain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addresses = [
        'user1@domain.com',
        'user1@anotherdomain.com',
        'user2@org.domain.com',
    ]
    print filter(lambda address: address_in_domain(address, 'domain.com'), addresses)
    # Prints: ['user1@domain.com', 'user2@org.domain.com']
```